# Width of login button of facebook when commenting, on mobiles

Tags: android, html, css, facebook

Im browsing my site on mobile phone. An article can be commented:

The problem is, when Im not logged in, a button appears to log in. But it looks alike:

```
|                     |
|                     |
|Login here to send po|
|                     |
|                     |
```

so (in my native language) the button has more width than the width of device. How to set 100% width for this button?

EDIT: sorry I forgot:

```
<div class="flbCont" style="background-color: red; width: 100%;">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="fladinflakk" data-numposts="5"  width="100%" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By your description its hard to have idea whats going on. Give some html/css or some url so i have a better idea. My guess is width: 100% should work for you in case its not check what width is applied on button container.

Comment: @Josh Powell, it doesnt work. The button is still widther than the window

Comment: Then you need to post some of your html/css so we can see why it doesn't work. If you look at the demo in my answer you can see it works.

Comment: done, I forgot doing that

Comment: @JohnSmith You need to isolate your styles in their own css file. Do not use inline-styles if you want something to be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I am going to use media queries to change the width from a fixed size (300px) to 100% width.

Here is the media query that will change the styles when it detects a change in size and device.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    .login {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Make sure you include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">
```

in your `head` tag. This will allow the media queries to detect the device and then know to make the changes.

Here is a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3R73P/1/)